# Euclidean division $n$ and $m$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, contest-math

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\bigl(\sum_{m = 1}^ {n}n\bmod m\bigl)$

Where $n\bmod m $ is the remainder of the Euclidean division of $n$ by $m$

I would like to know if I am right or if something is missing:

$n \bmod m=n-m\left \lfloor \frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor$ and so
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{m=1}^n(n \bmod m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{m=1}^n\left(n-m\left \lfloor \frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor\right)=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{m=1}^nm\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor \\
&=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{m}{n}\left \lfloor \frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor=1-\int_0^1x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor dx =1-\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x^3}\,dx\\&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{n}{x^3}\,dx 
=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) =1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1/2}{n(n+1)^2}\\[1ex]
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{align}

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: @PrismaApostatico, you're probably correct, but how did you get that $\int_0^1 x\lfloor \dfrac{1}{x}\rfloor dx= \int_1^\infty \dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^3} dx$?

Comment: Also, this might be some identity or something, but why were you able to perform your last step? How did you get $\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$?

Comment: The last step used the identity
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$and the telescoping sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)=1$$By using these two, the last step can be evaluated as:
\begin{align*}
1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}&=1-\left(\frac{\pi^2}6-1\right)-\frac12(1)+\frac12\left(\frac{\pi^2}6-1\right)\\
&=1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\end{align*}